# Windows 8 bootable disc

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, dvd

My friend given a non bootable dvd with

**Files**

Setup file
Autorun file
bootmgr
bootmgr.efi **etc**

**Folders**

Boot
Sources
Support
efi

I am using XP. I used Burnaware and converted to .iso file, and by using Windows 7 usb/dvd download tool i burned iso to dvd, but it does not `boot`.

Is anything i did is wrong? What should i do to make it boot?

Comment: iso and bootable iso is diffrent,check your iso is bootable or not http://superuser.com/questions/440035/how-can-i-check-whether-an-iso-image-is-bootable

Comment: @Vignesh4303 yes thats why i converted to bootable using `Windows 7 usb/dvd download tool` after making iso. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look: http://www.pcmech.com/article/how-to-create-a-bootable-cd-with-imgburn/

ImgBurn is a popular free application for write data to CD/DVDs and creating ISO image files. Concerning the ISO specifically, yes it can make bootable discs. This is very useful for creating emergency recovery discs.

ImgBurn is free: http://www.imgburn.com

Comment: Is the files mentioned is from a bootable dvd?

Comment: I have not understood your question, sry ... The difference between the bootable and not bootable CD/DVD is the presence of the boot sector with the magic code - the video helps you to do it by using a free tool ImgBurn - OK?

Comment: Can i convert that files to bootable dvd?

Comment: Yes, you take your data / files and create a bootable DVD. ImgBurn: Create an image file from files on your computer or network - or you can write the files directly to a disc